# Image container blows up to whole page in bootstrap

Tags: image, frontend, responsive, bootstrap-5

[image: Screenshot]I'm obviously doing something wrong but this is my Day 2 with Bootstrap. I have a fluid container with two rows. On the first row I've got a title and an image. That image - even though I reduced the height and have it set to responsive, causes that second column in the first row to basically extend to almost the whole page. When I remove the image, the world makes sense. When I put the image back, the container blows up. Happens with any image so it isn't the image, it is my bad bootstrap.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A basic website with Bootstrap #1</title>
    <!-- Including Bootstrap here-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-secondary">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="title-text text-light">Welcome to this Bootstrap Site #1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="masterchef.png" class="img-responsive h-25" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class="subtitle-text text-light">A site to learn Bootstrap well</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Tried using the thumbnail class, tried looking through Bootstrap docs, tried reordering to see if that helps. Did not help.

Comment: Yes you are doing mistake here. <div class="col">. in bootstrap "col" class sets a column to take up an equal amount of the available width, while the "col-6" class sets a column to take up 6 of the 12 available columns.

Answer (score 0):

To fix these kinds of errors you need to learn how columns work in bootstrap:

[image: how columns work in bootstrap]

[You can read more about the columns here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/)

The bootstrap columns are divided in this way, currently in your code you have entered only `col` which means they are columns that do not specify their size but fit the next columns;

Instead, in this example, the columns are expressed and you can command the display from mobile to desktop:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A basic website with Bootstrap #1</title>
    <!-- Including Bootstrap here-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-secondary">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                <h1 class="title-text text-light">Welcome to this Bootstrap Site #1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/526/683/png-clipart-take-out-chef-s-uniform-cafe-yuva-indian-cuisine-master-chef-thumbnail.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            <!--col-12 means that on all devices it will be 100% width magnitude-->
                <h2 class="subtitle-text text-light">A site to learn Bootstrap well</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--<div class="container-fluid menu-options">
        <div class="col">
            <button type = "button" class="btn mx-1 btn-primary">Home</button>
            <button type = "button" class="btn mx-1 btn-primary">Men's</button>
            <button type = "button" class="btn mx-1 btn-primary">Women's</button>
            <button type = "button" class="btn mx-1 btn-primary">Clearance</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
-->
</body>
</html>
```

(Did you see that? with the simple addition of the `md` class, but there are many others!)

In this case I inserted two columns in the row, so that from mobile the view would be split in two and after the tablet (`md`) would display

[read more about bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/)

Answer (score 0):

I got help offline. The main issue isn’t with Bootstrap, but with how percentages work. I had the h-25 class on the  element. The h-25 class attempts to set the height of an element to 25% of its parent. However, percentages only work properly when the parent has a well-defined/fixed height. When the parent doesn’t have a well-defined height, the browser enters a kind of feedback loop as it tries to adjust the set the  height to a percentage while also adjusting the parent height to contain it.

Solutions

The easiest solution is to remove “h-25” and set a fixed height on the

[image: Option 1]

Another option is to set a fixed height on the parent so that the percentage can be calculated definitively.

[image: Option 2]

I went with the first option as putting a size on the image made it responsive where it doesn't overflow the container on smaller viewports.